# How to use scaffolding template of grails 2.4.4 in grails 3.0

Tags: grails

I have developed a project using grails 2.4.4 and so happy with the automation generation code tool by command : `grails install-templates` and `grails generate-all com.domain.DomainClass`.

The problem when I update to version 3.0 is that customizing template style is really hard, I spent whole day to learn but now decide to give up . Version 3.0 uses the field plugin `org.grails.plugins:fields:2.1.5`. :(

In version 2.4.4, I customized and changed the default template in my own, and it worked well with my css style.

My question is that can I use my old template for 3.0 grails project. I tried by it throws error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easier to customize as well in Grails 3. Go to your scaffolding template directory

> your_project\src\main\templates\scaffolding

You can see there `create.gsp` `edit.gsp` `index.gsp` `show.gsp`.
Just use your own CSS class there and then generate scaffolding. You will get your desired style in your next view files.

Comment: Grails 3.0 using field plugin, it quite hard for me to using this one.